# How do I get access to R&D sessions in F1 2010?

Tags: xbox-360

I'm playing F1 2010 and am not long into my career.  In the garage before a race it says that you can participate in R&D sessions to get new modifications for your car to improve its performance.  However, I can't see how to start an R&D session.

Does anybody know how to start an R&D session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be somewhat random in its availability, but the frequency depends on how good your team is. However, if you become the number 1 driver for your team where you can control the level of R&D taken on by your team, and setting it higher will bring about more opportunities.

> The race engineer will likely not give you a new objective every race, at least initially, as you start with the lesser teams and an intermediate path setting by default. This can change however, when the players team promotes you into the number one drivers slot, giving you the choice to further your research & development or curtail it in favor of improving next years package

[Source](http://www.brighthub.com/video-games/console/articles/103146.aspx)